# Reusable code in userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm trying to write a simple userscript (for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey) but I can't quite get it working. The goal is to add a link when the page loads, then change the URL (`href`) whenever the element's `mouseup()` triggers. The triggered code uses new attributes from the declared elements, so they need to be set again.

The main thing I tried was wrapping the reusable code in `function run() { /* code */ }` (with the necessary tweaks to do the correct thing whether being called on page load or on mouseup), but this returns an error that `run() is not defined`. How can I properly reuse code in a userscript like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // REUSABLE CODE
    var projI=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var projE=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var center_lonlat=(/* variable declaration */);
    var topleft=(/* variable declaration */);
    var bottomright=(/* variable declaration */);
    lat=Math.round(center_lonlat.lat * 1000000)/1000000;
    lon=Math.round(center_lonlat.lon * 1000000)/1000000;
    spn=/* variable declaration */;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div .olControlAttribution').append('<a id="WMEtoGMM" href=" \
        /* link here that uses above variables */"'+ \
        'target="_blank">Open new page</a>');
});

$('div .view-area.olMap #mouseupElement').mouseup(function() {
    $('#WMEtoGMM').attr('href', 'URL HERE');
});
```

Comment: this is a `greasemonkey` and `tampermonkey` `userscript` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, that's correct.

Comment: and this is done in a page that has jQueery loaded and the OpenLayers library loaded as well?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, also correct.

Comment: well, that's the obvious source of errors taken care of - to be honest, I can't really see what you are trying to achieve - the code you posted is clearly syntactically wrong, `pseudo code` is hard to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, you have some code in the document-ready that you want to be able run as required after document-ready.

But, more importantly, you want to be able to use the result of that reusable function.

So move the code out into its own function that returns an object and call that function, ie:

```
function calc_values() {
    // call this function something that makes more sense in the context
    // REUSABLE CODE
    var obj = {};  // create a new object to store the values
    obj.projI=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    obj.projE=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    obj.center_lonlat=(/* variable declaration */);
    obj.topleft=(/* variable declaration */);
    obj.bottomright=(/* variable declaration */);
    obj.lat=Math.round(center_lonlat.lat * 1000000)/1000000;
    obj.lon=Math.round(center_lonlat.lon * 1000000)/1000000;
    obj.spn=/* variable declaration */;
    return obj;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // this replaces the original doc-ready call, but doesn't look like it's needed
    calc_values(); 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = calc_values();
    // you can now use obj.projI etc to generate your link
    $('div .olControlAttribution').append('<a id="WMEtoGMM" href=" \
        /* link here that uses above variables */"'+ \
        'target="_blank">Open new page</a>');
});

$('div .view-area.olMap #mouseupElement').mouseup(function() {
    var obj = calc_values();
    // you can now use obj.projI etc to generate your link
    $('#WMEtoGMM').attr('href', 'URL HERE');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I was making it much more difficult than it needed to be. The problem now is that `$(document).ready()` is firing before `obj` can be used (element is not defined). I tried using `$(window).load()`, but the code doesn't run at all.